# How can we detect cosmic background microwave radiation?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, cosmic-microwave-background

From my understanding this stuff expands at or near the speed of light -- and it's origins are that of the creation of this universe (via big bang).  Obviously, our planet does not expand from origin at this speed, so why is it possible for us to detect it?

Comment: It's microwave radiation. We detect it with a microwave antenna and a cooled preamplifier or a bolometer.

Comment: It is technically noise, and that is present in every receiver at every frequency.

Comment: @CuriousOne of course, but doesn't this radiation propagate faster than the expansion of our planet?  Wouldn't it already be past us if it originated at the same time as the BB?

Comment: With equipment specially designed for this task, specifically: [COBE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_Background_Explorer), [WMAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson_Microwave_Anisotropy_Probe), and [Planck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_(spacecraft)).

Comment: @KyleKanos  Perhaps I should've stated 'why' can we detect it.

Comment: Our planet *isn't* expanding and the CMB is all pervading

Comment: @KyleKanos how is it possible that it is 'all pervading'.  Are you saying our planet is static in the heavens and doesn't experience Inflation?

Comment: I don't think you've understood [inflation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflation_(cosmology)) properly (in fact, understanding it correctly actually would *answer* the question in your comment above).

Comment: In a homogeneous and isotropic universe every point in the universe looks like it's at the center. Looks are deceiving. Are you asking why there is a CMB here AND everywhere else? Because the CMB here didn't originate in the same physical location as the CMB that is being detected somewhere else.

Comment: @CuriousOne okay, but universe is expanding, does more CMB spontaneously come into existence to ensure that CMB is still everywhere?  That seems like it cannot possibly be true.

Comment: The CMB was emitted 300,000 years after the big bang. Since then it has been traveling mostly unchanged trough interstellar space. Like I said, your model of where the CMB was emitted is wrong. It wasn't emitted on one 2d surface but in the whole 3d volume of the universe.

Comment: @CuriousOne thank you. your last sentence furthered my understanding most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very common misconception that matter exploded outwards from a point in a pre-existing universe at the time of the Big Bang. This is not, however, what the Big Bang theory claims. Instead, the universe was still infinitely more dense than it is today, but was the same shape (in the topological sense). If the universe is infinite in size today, then it was infinite in size at the Big Bang; if the universe is like a game of Asteroids today, where it repeats every 20 billion light years or something, then at the time of the Big Bang it was just shrunk so that it repeated every tiny-tiny fraction of 20 billion light years. Since then, all of space has been expanding in all directions, stretching matter and radiation out and making them less dense.

[Addition]
Here is [a useful GIF image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_expansion_of_space#mediaviewer/File:Raisinbread.gif) (which I cannot embed because the format is not accepted). It shows raisins in a piece of bread that become farther apart as the bread expands. The raisins are analogous to bits of matter in the universe, while the bread represents expanding spacetime. Each raisin is at rest with respect to the bread around it and is not moving through the bread - the raisins aren't exploding outwards from the center of the bread. In the same way, matter in the universe is not exploding outwards from a common center. Instead, galaxies are mostly at rest with respect to the expanding spacetime (one says they are ``comoving'').

So, we can see the CMB because the radiation that hits us didn't start from the same point as us during the Big Bang. Rather, it started at some other place (i.e. some other raisin), and has travelled to us (at our raisin) through the expanding universe (bread).

Note: Bits and pieces of this answer were in the comments, but I don't think any of them completely addressed this point. For one, inflation is not crucial, and secondly, although @CuriousOne's comment on 2D surface / 3D volume has helped the OP somewhat, the OP might still have this fundamental misconception, and just think that the CMB was created within the sphere of expanding matter 300k years after the Big Bang.

Comment: You are right. Somebody should give the OP a working mental picture. I think you could expand on your answer a little bit more, maybe with an image or two (preferably not of explosions)?

Comment: An image would be good, maybe that chocolate chip cookie one that is popular. I'll try to find one that is free to use.

Comment: I think that one might help.